# How to set value for object in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to ios programming,i created a class books which takes some values dynamically,so i am trying to set value for some params in book  object,i am getting exception.

code:

```
Book
{
@property (strong,nonatomic)  NSString *bookId;
@property (strong,nonatomic)  NSString *bookStatus;
@property (strong,nonatomic)  NSString *bookName;
 }
Book * book =[Book alloc]init];
[book setValue:@"textbook" forKey:@"bookName"]; //not working
book.bookStatus=@"textbook"  //not working
[book setbookStatus:@"textbook"];  //not working
}
```

I am getting exception [_NSCFDictionary setbookStatus] unrecognized selector

Comment: Is this your actual code?  How is you `Book` class defined? What is the `@interface code`? The exception shows that you tried to call `setBookStatus` on an instance of `NSDictionary`.  You can just say `book.bookName=@"textbook";`

Comment: try book.bookName = @"bookName"

Comment: i wrote code in shorter format for understanding,i tried but still getting exception @PKT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use,

```
self.bookName = @"yourBookName";
self.bookStatus = @"bookStatus";
```

You can use `self` to call current class object likw `this` in `java`.

If you want to access it from another class then import Book to that class and make instance of it and by that instance you can call it,s property like,

```
Book *myBook = [[Book alloc]init];
NSString *str = myBook.bookName;
```

hope this will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create the properties in the .h(Book.h) class to make properties as public.
Then you can directly access the properties by dot(.)

```
Book *book = [[Book alloc] init];
book.bookId = @“1234”
book.bookName = @“name”
```